# Can I redirect a request with code 302 to another port without using the HOST variable?

Tags: http, redirect, language-agnostic

In the HTTP protocol, there are multiple status codes that can be used to redirect a request to another URL, such as `301 Moved Permanently` or `302 Found`. To my knowledge, the target URL can either contain a host (`http://example.com/example.html`) or let the host implicitly be the current host (`/example.html`).

When using the first form, one can redirect to a non-standard port (`http://example.com:8080/example.html`). **How can this be done when not specifying the host?**

Currently, I parse the `HOST` request header and build the new URL. But AFAIK, that header is not strictly required to be sent, so I want to avoid it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't specify just the port in a redirect. And yes, the "Host" header field *is* strictly required in HTTP/1.1.